# Alternative mapping for <Tab> key via YouCompleteMe

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-you-complete-me

I have tried **many** of the available online instructions on remapping my **`<Tab>`** key in my `vimrc` file but none of them have any effect.  If I run `:map! <Tab> ᐅ` directly from command entry it'll work, but not from `vimrc`.

When I run `:verbose imap <Tab>` I get the following.

```
i  <Tab>       * pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "\<Tab>"
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
```

Looking at the source code for YouCompleteMe I see a variable of `key` is present which is mapped to **`<Tab>`** if it's not in completion mode.  **How can I set what the `<Tab>` key is when not in completion mode for YouCompleteMe?**

Comment: You can override the plugin mapping in a file in `~/.vim/after/plugin/mystuff.vim`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to: https://github.com/micbou — [answer](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2587#issuecomment-289555540)

> If what you want is inserting the ᐅ symbol when the completion menu is not visible, adding these lines to your vimrc should do the trick:
>
> ```
> " Remove <Tab> from the list of keys mapped by YCM.
> let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<Down>']
> inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "ᐅ"
> ```